# Recursively get message field names in ROS2

Tags: ros2, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have the handy `rosidl_runtime_py.message_to_csv()` method for converting a message to CSV, but is there a similar function that will recursively get the field names so I can print out a CSV header as well?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386628/recursively-get-message-field-names-in-ros2/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2021-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it!

```
def recursive_items(ordered_dict):
    for key, value in ordered_dict.items():
        if type(value) is collections.OrderedDict:
            yield from recursive_items(value)
        else:
            yield (key, value)

def print_headers(record):
    print(','.join([key for key, _ in recursive_items(rosidl_runtime_py.message_to_ordereddict(record))]))
```

I'd missed the API `rosidl_runtime_py.message_to_ordereddict()` which gives me the message with names and values in a nested `OrderedDict`, so I iterate over that to pull out the keys from the leaf nodes.

---

Originally posted by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) with karma: 541 on 2021-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0